# Ionic page not showing back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have installed this ionic sample project as a base using this command:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

and when I add this back button to subpage header it won't show up:

```
 <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
       <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

As I understand, there should be history in order for buttons to be shown. So, isn't the official sample suppose to have browsing history within the route? Do you guys have a simple working example that would have tabs and as well as navigation buttons in place? Otherwise, I have no clue how to implement it with best practice.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this by setting defult page **defaultHref="/home"**

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
       <ion-back-button defaultHref="/home"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```